# Tableau Public, Box Plots: combine 4 rows into 1 with 4 plots per month

Tags: boxplot, tableau-api

I have a Tableau Public sheet with 4 years of data.

Each day has a value, and I am showing those daily values as a box plot - one for each month of each year.
Currently it is set up as 4 rows (1 for each year), and 12 columns.

**See here:**

https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/boxplotsbyyearmonth-dailyvalues/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=no

What I want to do is drop to a single row, and show all 4 box plots side by side within each month, colored by year.
I can't elaborate what exactly I have tried, as I am new to Tableau, and have done a lot of clicking around looking for options, and have tried searching various sites and Google, to no avail.

Is there a simple trick to this, or is it something complex I have to do to?

**UPDATE:**

I have figured out how to get them lined up correctly, by dragging the year dimension to the columns section, which I had tried, but then I had to reset the other dimensions, and it took.

What I still can't figure out is the coloring.
By dragging the year to the color property, it colors the outliers, which are separate marks, but the box plots are not affected.

Answer (score 0):

When you pull the year field to color it will color the marks (all of them, including the outliers). If you want to change the color of the box plot container you need to select it and right click.

I made some edits, let me know if this is what you were trying to accomplish:
https://public.tableausoftware.com/views/boxplots_0/Sheet1?:embed=y&:display_count=no

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But what I really want is for the box plots (fill and line colors) themselves to be colored by year, not just the marks. Is this possible?

Comment: Not that I am aware of. When you change the look and feel of the box you change them all, there is no way to edit only a subset.

Comment: Hm. Well that's very counter intuitive, and seems like a giant oversight. You can customize every other chart type's colors by category, but not box plots...  Thanks.